# Building a query from columns in a table

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I have a local table which includes a number of columns. Some of these colums are full, some empty
They consist of metadata on other tables such as:

```
SCHEMA TABLE_NAME DRIVER_TABLE JOIN_COND_1 JOIN_COND_2
```

Here's an example of what some dummy data may look like:

```
SCHEMA TABLE_NAME DRIVER_TABLE JOIN_COND_1 JOIN_COND_2
BOB    TRUCKS     NULL         NULL        NULL
BOB    VANS       USER.XXX     A.ID=B.ID   NULL
BOB    CARS       USER.XXX     A.ID=B.ID   B.END_DTE >= '01-DEC-2018'
```

The reason the table exists is to create a means to count rows in another database.

I need to come up with a means by which I can obtain output like the following using the table:

```
SCHEMA TABLE_NAME COUNT
BOB    TRUCKS     878908
BOB    VANS       7899
BOB    CARS       876
```

The metadata table will be the source of the query, but the query should be in one block of code. I'm not sure where to begin.

The driver table is a list of id's to limit the count and is only to be used if it's there.

So, the first row, where no "driver table" is listed, just a NULL would be simply:

```
Select SCHEMA, TABLE_NAME, count(*) COUNT from METADATA;
```

The second query would have to use the driver table and join:

```
Select SCHEMA, TABLE_NAME, count(*) COUNT from METADATA A, USER.XXX B
WHERE A.ID=B.ID;
```

And the third query would be:

```
Select SCHEMA, TABLE_NAME, count(*) COUNT from METADATA A, USER.XXX B
WHERE A.ID=B.ID
AND B.END_DTE >= '01-DEC-2018';
```

So, all of this sql is to be built from what is in the metadata columns.

I had thought of some sort of group of loops based to get the columns into variables,
and then form an if, then, else logic.

```
DECLARE
l_sql_1    VARCHAR2(100);
l_sql_2    VARCHAR2(100);
l_sql_3    VARCHAR2(100);
l_sql_4    VARCHAR2(100);


BEGIN
l_sql_1 := 'SELECT SCHEMA||'.'||TABLE_NAME FROM METADATA';
l_sql_2 := 'SELECT DRIVER_TABLE FROM METADATA';
l_sql_3 := 'SELECT JOIN_COND_1 FROM METADATA';
l_sql_4 := 'SELECT JOIN_COND_2  FROM METADATA';
```

Does anyone have any ideas on how I might accomplish this please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `dynamic sql` as

```
SQL> set serveroutput on;
SQL> declare
 v_sql    varchar2(4000);
 v_schema varchar2(40);
 v_table  varchar2(40); 
 v_count  pls_integer;
begin
  dbms_output.put_line('schema  table   count');                       
  dbms_output.put_line('------  -----   -----');
 for c in ( select * from metadata )
 loop
   v_schema := c.schema;
   v_table  := c.table_name;
   v_sql := 'select count(*) from '||c.table_name||' a ';
  if c.driver_table is not null then
   v_sql := v_sql ||' join '||c.driver_table||' b on a.id=b.id ';
    if c.join_cond_2 is not null then
     v_sql := v_sql ||' where '||c.join_cond_2;     
    end if;   
  end if;
  execute immediate v_sql into v_count;
  dbms_output.put_line(v_schema||'     '||v_table||'    '||v_count);
 end loop;   
end;
```

Answer (score -1):

If you're using Transact-SQL, then you can probably tap into the system views.

```
SELECT SCH.[name] AS [SCHEMA]
, ST.[name] AS [TABLE_NAME]
, SUM(SP.[rows]) AS [ROW_COUNT]
FROM sys.tables AS ST
INNER JOIN sys.partitions AS SP ON ST.object_id = SP.object_id
INNER JOIN sys.schemas AS SCH ON SCH.schema_id = ST.schema_id
AND SP.[index_id] IN (0, 1)
--WHERE ST.[name] LIKE '<your table name>' + '%' -- Optional
GROUP BY SCH.[name], ST.[name]
```